# Intrinsic carrier concentration of a semiconductor without Boltzmann approximation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, fermi-energy

The carrier concentration of conduction band of a intrinsic semiconductor at a temperature $T$ is
$$n_i=\frac{1}{2\pi^2}\left(\frac{ 2m_e^* }{ \hbar^2}\right)^{3/2}\int_{E_c}^{\infty}\sqrt{E-E_c}f_{FD}(E,T)dE$$
where $m_e^*$ is electron effective mass and $f_{FD}$ is the Fermi-Dirac distribution function. Take $E_F$ to be the Fermi-Energy. Then by Boltzman approximation we get $$n_i=2\left(\frac{ m_c^* k_BT}{2\pi \hbar^2}\right)^{3/2}e^{-(E_c-E_F)/k_BT}$$
when $(E_c-E_F)/k_BT>>1$.

But what will be the exact carrier concentration? (Without using approximations)

Answer (score 1):

This is a good work. Refer "Complete Fermi–Dirac integral" which will confirm your result.
`https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_Fermi%E2%80%93Dirac_integral`

Comment: THank you @RoseH